# Grails: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql: and jdbc:sqlserver:

Tags: mysql, sql-server, grails, jdbc, drivers

I know that this questions discussed many times and I read many information about this but I could not find solution for my example.

I have a project in Grails and I put those jars in `/lib/` folder:

```
sqljdbc4.jar

mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
```

My controller code is:

```
import groovy.sql.*
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

    class TestConnectionController {

        def index() { 
            ---example---------------------------------------------------------
            def dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://mysql_server:3306/"
            def dbUser = "login"
            def dbPassword = "password"
            def dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)
            sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM TABLE") {render it}
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            or
            ---example---------------------------------------------------------
            def dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://mssql_server:1433'
            def dbUser = "login"
            def dbPassword = "password"
            def dbDriver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
            def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)
            sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM [TABLE]") {render it}
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------              
        }
    }
```

I did `grails clean` and `--reflesh-dependencies` many times - it doesn't help. I use `ggts-3.6.4.` and `grails-2.4.4` and JDK folder for IDE is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` Also I tryed add jars to project's `Java Build Path` at `Libraries` section. 
This project worked on Windows Server 2010. After as I move it on Windows Server 2012 RC2 I cann't run him.

DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    username = "user"
    password = "password"
    driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql_server;databaseName=login"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql_server;databaseName=login"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql_server;databaseName=login"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using MySQL drivers? I'm confused.

Comment: @Emmanuel Rosa there are two separate connections as example first using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` second - `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`. I wrote ` or` in my code.

Comment: Ah i see. One more question. Is there a reason you're not using dependency management to get the drivers and then using gorm to query the database?

Comment: @Emmanuel Rosa I used DataSource.groovy also (added to main post) It is also not help to resolve the problem.

Comment: So basically your missing the driver. Unfortunately I couldn't find it in maven, so I don't know how to specify the dependency in build.groovy :(